# In ruby on rails is it necessary to save after create?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is it necessary to explicitly save after create? If so, what's the difference between new and create? I notice in a previous app I saved the wrong collection but the created collection is saved anyway.

Comment: a good read: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-users#sec-creating_user_objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you don't need to save after Create.  Create does both "new" and "save" for you.